# Constructors in the Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, module-pattern

When using the module pattern in javascript how should constructors be defined, if at all. I would like my constructor to fit into a standard module pattern and not be global.

Why doesn't something like this work, is it complete and total nonsense?

```
var HOUSE = function() {
    return {
        Person: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.name = "john";
            function name() {
                return self.name;
            }
        }
    };
}();

var me = new HOUSE.Person();
alert(me.name());
```

Comment: `self.name` is a string `"john"` so you can't invoke it. Note that your local function `name` is not exported anywhere.

Comment: Updated question, but it made a perfectly good answer make no sense so changed it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bring the method out, and attach it to the Person prototype.  But when you do, you'll have a name property, and a name method, which won't work, so consider renaming the latter

```
HOUSE.Person.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}
```

OR, you could just attach it to `this`, and make getName a privileged method:

```
  Person: function() {
        this.name = "john";
        this.getName = function() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think there you have a little syntax issue. :)

Comment: So assigning `var self = this` so I this doesn't change is not required?

Comment: @whatsthebeef - assigning `var self = this` would definitely be a good idea if you were keeping that private function (what you defined as `function name()`) - when that private function were to be called, `this` would be the window object, so to get the "actualy" this, you'd save it to `self`, which the private func would close over.  But since you really want this name function to be a public method, you no longer need that self variable

Comment: So exposing it as a public method means that this will always refer to `Person` and not `window`

Comment: When you call a method on an object—say `foo.method()`—inside of the method, `this` will always be the object on which you're calling the method.  So in that example, `this` will be `foo` inside of `method()`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost fine. However the function `name()` was not public but the variable was so you were trying to execute the variable causing an error. Add the function `getName` onto the object and call that instead:

```
var HOUSE = function() {
    return {
        Person: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.name = "john";
            self.getName = function() {
                return self.name;
            }
        }
    };
}();

var me = new HOUSE.Person();
alert(me.getName());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8nSbP/

Answer (score 2):

Using `var` and `function foo() {}` (the latter as a declaration, which means "just" `function foo() {}` without assigning it), create local symbols. So, the function is not available outside the constructor.

Whatever you want to expose (make public), you should assign to `this` (or `self` since you defined `self = this`):

```
self.getName = function() {
    return self.name;
};
```

Note that you already used `name`, so I gave function another name. If you wanted to make the `name` string local, and expose the function, then they can have the same name since there is no conflict. E.g.:

```
var name = "john";

self.name = function() {
    return name;
};
```